# use recursion to find values of nested dict and return keys of the dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have an exercise where a dictionary of birthdays is given as follows:

```
    birthdays = 
    {"Anne": {"month":"Jan","day":"27"},
    "Mike":{"month":"Feb","day":"13"},
    "Nicolas":{"month":"Jun","day":14}, 
    "Marta": {"month":"Jan","day":16}}
```

The question is to define a function which, given a month, prints a list of all the people who have birthdays in that month, with the dates.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
    def birthbymonth(book, month):
        for k,v in book.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                birthbymonth(v,month)           
            else:
                if month == v:
                    print(book)
```

Which when called birthbymonth(birthdays,"Jan") prints:

```
    {'month': 'Jan', 'day': '27'}
    {'month': 'Jan', 'day': 16}
```

Yet I dont know how to also print the names of the people that have birthdays then.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any reason to use recursion here.

```
def birthbymonth(book, month):
    for person,birthday in book.items():
        if birthday['month'] == month:
            print('{}: {} {}'.format(person, birthday['month'], birthday['day']))
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, there is no need for recursion. Instead, use a list comprehension:

```
birthdays = {"Anne": {"month":"Jan","day":"27"},
"Mike":{"month":"Feb","day":"13"},
"Nicolas":{"month":"Jun","day":14}, 
"Marta": {"month":"Jan","day":16}}
def dates(birthdays, month):
   return ["{}: {}".format(a, b['day']) for a, b in birthdays.items() if b['month'] == month]

print(dates(birthdays, 'Jan'))
```

Output:

```
['Marta: 16', 'Anne: 27']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to use recursion (not recommended for this problem), you can make a few modifications to your existing code:

```
birthdays = {
    "Anne": {"month":"Jan","day":27},
    "Mike": {"month":"Feb","day":13},
    "Nicolas": {"month":"Jun","day":14},
    "Marta": {"month":"Jan","day":16}
}

def birthbymonth(book, month):
    names = []
    for k,v in book.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            names += [(k, book[k]["day"])] if birthbymonth(v,month) is True else []
        else:
            if month == v:
                return True
    return names

print(birthbymonth(birthdays, 'Jan'))
#[('Marta', 16), ('Anne', 27)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
birthdays = {"Anne": {"month":"Jan","day":"27"},
             "Mike": {"month":"Feb","day":"13"},
             "Nicolas": {"month":"Jun","day":14}, 
             "Marta": {"month":"Jan","day":16}}

{k: v['day'] for k, v in birthdays.items() if v['month']=='Jan'}

# {'Anne': '27', 'Marta': 16}
```